# How to check if a substring exists in a string given it is separated by a delimiter?

Tags: php, regex, substring

How can I check if the text "abc" exists in a string but not "abcd"?

For example, if the mail string is "abcdef", "abcd,ef", or something like that, where "abc" has letters to either side, it should return false. However, something like "abc", "abc.def" or "abc,def" should return true.

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer at some point. It'll give you a little extra rep and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `\b`:

```
\babc\b
```

This will not match for anything like `athingabcisdef`, `abcdef`, or `aabcc`, but it will match `hello, abc!` and `abc,why?`

`\b` matches at word boundaries, which basically means "match if one of the characters to either side is a word character, and the other isn't", though it also considers the beginning and end of the string to not be word characters. Note that `\w` includes `_`, so if you want to match things like `a_abc_c`, you'll have to add that in yourself.

You can find an online test of that regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/jW4yR2/2) ("PCRE" is perl regexes, which is what `preg_match` uses -- the `preg` means `p`erl `reg`ular expressions)

Comment: @sln Really? I've had issues before where it didn't and I expected it to, though that was in a different language. Lemme test it out and edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is a word boundary definition `(?:(?:^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9_]))(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_])|(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9_])(?:$|(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9_])))`

Comment: @sln And a quick test with PHP confirms that you're right. Thanks for the tip! I've updated my answer.